# Pycaffe Installation in windows

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, caffe

I had to work around with caffe in python so i tried to Build caffe for windows using opencv and vs2013
and for cpu only mode the process was sucessfull and build completed with few warnings and no Errors
after that i copied the build file into lib/site packages in my anaconda package so that i will be able to use it 
but after that i tried to **import caffe**  it shows error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1cca3aa1f8c5> in <module>()
----> 1 import caffe

F:\python\lib\site-packages\caffe\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
      2 from ._caffe import set_mode_cpu, set_mode_gpu, set_device, Layer, get_solver, layer_type_list
      3 from .proto.caffe_pb2 import TRAIN, TEST
      4 from .classifier import Classifier
      5 from .detector import Detector

F:\python\lib\site-packages\caffe\pycaffe.py in <module>()
     11 import numpy as np
     12 
---> 13 from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
     14         RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
     15 import caffe.io

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Thanks for Help in Advance 
Can anyone get me through this error and import caffe successfully

Comment: have you built pycaffe as well?

Comment: I build only pycaffe with caffelib in caffe-windows master

Comment: does the error is due to build problem or due to dll problem or path issue in environment variable

Comment: Thank God i am finally able to install caffe with python in ubuntu thanks all for you help

Comment: @MidhunMohan: How did you solve this on windows? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @ Hossein in windows the dll Files should be in the correct location rather than that any caffe installation tutorial is enough ..the Path Set for everything from caffe directory to protoc compiler should be precise and activated and for pycaffe you could use it with anaconda since it has an inbuild cmd for activating path

Comment: @MidhunMohan: May I have your email address? I have caffe and pycaffe compiled and ready, I am also using Anaconda, but Im facing errors, I would be grateful If you could give me you email to further talk about this

Comment: @ Hossein I think We could Have the conversion like this so Someone New Who is Facing the same Problem Could Find a Solution for It..

Comment: what are the errors you are facing right now?

Comment: consider this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/34853070/2736559 
for example as the first python related one!

Comment: whats the issue over there

Comment: @MidhunMohan How did you build caffe and pycaffe on windows?

Comment: using visual studio @Mavie

Comment: @ I am also trying to build caffe using Visual Studio 2015, but getting errors.-[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325487/build-caffe-pycaffe-on-windows-using-visual-studio-error ]. please look  at it.