# Caffe install getting ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, caffe, jupyter-notebook, pycaffe

I am trying to compile and run the snippets posted [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb), which basically is going to let me visualize the network internals (feature maps).

I have successfully compiled `caffe` and `pycaffe` using the `caffe-windows` branch, And I have copied the caffe folder, into `T:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages` folder. Yet still, when I try to run this snippet of code in Jupyter notebook:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Make sure that caffe is on the python path:
caffe_root = 'TC:/Caffe/'  # this file is expected to be in {caffe_root}/examples
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root + 'python')

import caffe

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 10)
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'nearest'
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'

import os
if not os.path.isfile(caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel'):
    print("Downloading pre-trained CaffeNet model...")
    !../scripts/download_model_binary.py ../models/bvlc_reference_caffenet
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e7a8ec94e861> in <module>()
      8 sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root + 'python')
      9 
---> 10 import caffe

L:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\caffe\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver
      2 from ._caffe import set_mode_cpu, set_mode_gpu, set_device, Layer, get_solver
      3 from .proto.caffe_pb2 import TRAIN, TEST
      4 from .classifier import Classifier
      5 from .detector import Detector

L:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\caffe\pycaffe.py in <module>()
     11 import numpy as np
     12 
---> 13 from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver
     14 import caffe.io
     15 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

What's wrong here?

Note: I'm using `Anaconda2-2.4.1-Windows-x86_64.exe`.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763915/pycaffe-installation-in-windows

Comment: since you add `caffe_root + '/python'` manually into your `path` I don't suppose you need to copy the module to `site_packages`.

Comment: @Shai: Thanks, But there is nothing special about the first link! couldnt find any information in that!
so you mean is it redundant? If so, why in first place its declared like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's most likely a more specific dependency issue you are not seeing (Protobuf / OpenCV). First try using the [C++ API](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/cpp_classification.html) to load an example and make sure all the DLL's load. Then you can more confidently narrow things down to the Python side. I recommend the more recent windows caffe instructions based off the branch you're using:

https://initialneil.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/build-caffe-in-windows-with-visual-studio-2013-cuda-6-5-opencv-2-4-9/

I had to do a complete rebuild as detailed above (note that some dependencies are easier to find with NuGet). Also be on the lookout for the right protobuf binaries in various 3rdParty.zip files throughout the above blog.

If you are okay with a snapshot version of Caffe and you don't need to modify the project itself, the following binaries are *much* easier to install and get working:

https://initialneil.wordpress.com/2015/07/15/caffe-vs2013-opencv-in-windows-tutorial-i/

Comment: Thanks,I'll check this an report back. 
Altough I'm pretty sure the OpenCV is got to be fine, Im not sure about the proto buff though!)

Comment: you were right, protbuf was missing, I had to compile the protobuf package for anaconda and then the error is gone ;) 
by the way whats the meaning of this line? I'm not good with python, 
Thanks again
 `   !../scripts/download_model_binary.py ../models bvlc_reference_caffenet  `

is `!` an operator or something?

Comment: I think that's Jupyter syntax to start a process. Perhaps try Python `subprocess` or just manually run it :)