# Build caffe\Pycaffe on windows using Visual Studio--error?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to build caffe (libcaffe,pycaffe) on windows using Visual studio.
I downloaded the caffe-master project from below link

[Caffe for windows](https://github.com/microsoft/caffe)

using visual studio 2015 and open the solution caffe in it. enabled python support true to build

some nuget-packages were missing so restore them. for this followed the link

[How to install caffe in windows in five minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrzAF2sxHHM)

try to build the project but getting following errors:

```
C2059   syntax error: 'constant' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\layer.cpp)  libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 2525
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\layer.cpp) libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 2525    
C2059   syntax error: 'constant' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\data_reader.cpp)    libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 2525    
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\data_reader.cpp)   libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 2525    
C2059   syntax error: 'constant' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\layer.cpp)  libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 9806    
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\layer.cpp) libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 9806    
C2059   syntax error: 'constant' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\data_reader.cpp)    libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 9806    
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\data_reader.cpp)   libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 9806    
C2059   syntax error: 'constant' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\layers\base_data_layer.cpp) libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 2525    
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\layers\base_data_layer.cpp)    libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 2525    
C2059   syntax error: 'constant' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\layers\base_data_layer.cpp) libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 9806    
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\layers\base_data_layer.cpp)    libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 9806    
C1083   Cannot open include file: 'pyconfig.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\layer_factory.cpp) libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\NugetPackages\boost.1.66.0.0\lib\native\include\boost\python\detail\wrap_python.hpp 50  
C2059   syntax error: 'constant' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\parallel.cpp)   libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 2525    
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\parallel.cpp)  libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 2525    
C2059   syntax error: 'constant' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\parallel.cpp)   libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 9806    
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\parallel.cpp)  libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 9806    
C2059   syntax error: 'constant' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\util\blocking_queue.cpp)    libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 2525    
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\util\blocking_queue.cpp)   libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 2525    
C2059   syntax error: 'constant' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\util\blocking_queue.cpp)    libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 9806    
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file ..\..\src\caffe\util\blocking_queue.cpp)   libcaffe    D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h 9806    
C1083   Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory pycaffe D:\caffe-master\caffe-master\python\caffe\_caffe.cpp    1
```

I have already installed boost-python from nuget-packages but it is still showing 
    cannot  open include file Python.h

Comment: you can use prebuilt binaries right why building from source

Comment: check this https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4538

Comment: i think the error is because you haven't included boost-python packages to python lib or python path

Comment: @MidhunMohan prebuilt binaries are not available now on this link [https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows]. if you know other links please share.

Comment: check this it might be helpful https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6569#issuecomment-432491851 they are proving a conda installation way